# How do I connect to a PostgreSQL Database Server with Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to connect Django application with PostgreSQL Database Server on `cPanel / Namecheap hosting`. I have installed `PostgreSQL` in Django app using this command  `pip install psycopg2`. And in `settings.py` i have used this code

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
}
```

}

Comment: Might want to change your password, given that you've posted it here for everyone to see...

Comment: FYI, people can see edits. Some users can also see deleted questions. You should change that password.

Answer (score 3):

Try following configuration

```
DATABASES = {
    'default':{
       'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
       'NAME':'db_name',
       'USER':'username',
       'PASSWORD':'password',
       'HOST':'localhost',
       'POST':'5432',
      'ATOMATIC_REQUESTS':True,
    }
}
```